# Вывод RSS лент с других ресурсов

Tags: php, rss

Можно ли на своем сайте выводить RSS ленты с других ресурсов с помощью PHP? Если да, подскажите, пожалуйста, пример. Спасибо.

Comment: Суть такова - на сайте по запросу пользователя нужно вывести некоторую информацию, что записана в RSS на другом ресурсе. Возможно ли это, или есть другие методы?

Comment: http://phprec.ru/?Chtenie_RSS%01rassylok